# How create the Decay function in ElasticSearch DSL python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am querying the Elastic Search with [elasticsearch-dsl/2.0.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/elasticsearch-dsl/2.0.0)

```
 "linear": {
        "date": {
              "origin": "now", 
              "scale": "10d",
              "offset": "5d", 
              "decay" : 0.5 
        }
    }
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-decay

How to construct the linear function query with elasticsearch-dsl

Answer (score 4):

Try the following query

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch_dsl import Search, query

client = Elasticsearch()

s = Search(using=client)

function_score_query = query.Q(
        'function_score',
        query=query.Q('match', your_field='your_query'),
        functions=[
            query.SF('linear',date={"origin":"now","scale":"10d",
                                    "offset":"5d", "decay":0.5})
        ]
    )
```

If you print the `function_score_query.to_dict()` you will get

```
{
    'function_score': {
        'query': {
            'match': {
                'your_field': 'your_query'
            }
        },
        'functions': [{
            'linear': {
                'date': {
                    'origin': 'now',
                    'decay': 0.5,
                    'scale': '10d',
                    'offset': '5d'
                }
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

You could check the [test cases](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/3ebb486363b2c94172b81668e41fdb2411e5a022/test_elasticsearch_dsl/test_query.py#L284) on github to see how function score query can be used in DSL